# Fast Convert of large csv to geojson

Tags: python, csv, geojson

I have a csv with **6 millions of rows** and i need to convert it to a **geojson** file.

cloud solutions exists in the internet but it takes whole day to convert it.
Is there a quick way to do that with python ?

**UPDATE OF QUESTION :**

i tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586647/python-script-to-convert-csv-to-geojson) but i'm getting this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-0224e45ed66e> in <module>()
  5 with open('Documents/neo4j-community-3.3.5/import/train.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  6     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
----> 7     for pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude in reader:
  8         pickup_latitude,pickup_longitude = map(float,   (pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude))
  9         features.append(

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

this is my code :

```
import csv, json
from geojson import Feature, FeatureCollection, Point

features = []
with open('Documents/neo4j-community-3.3.5/import/train.csv', newline='')   as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude in reader:
    pickup_latitude,pickup_longitude = map(float, (pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude))
    features.append(
        Feature(
            geometry = Point((pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude)),

        )
    )

collection = FeatureCollection(features) 
with open("GeoObs.json", "w") as f:
f.write('%s' % collection)
```

*Note* :pickup_latitude and pickup_longitude are two columns in my csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you have more columns in your csv file than just two which the `for` statement expects. To fix this, you could take all columns and then analyze only the first two:

```
for cols in reader:
    pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude = map(float, cols[0:2])
```