# Convert 2 gb csv file to geojson

Tags: python, csv, mapreduce, geojson

I want to convert a huge csv **(2GB)** to the geojson format.

i use the solution of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586647/python-script-to-convert-csv-to-geojson)
but the script didn't stop since the morning .

is there another efficient way to convert big large csv file to geojson ?

Comment: Try Python iterators?

Comment: it is very huge data for python iterators( foreach and while).
solution would be with map-reduce i think or with spark !