# Converting CSV to Geojson with LineStrings

Tags: python, geojson, kepler.gl

I'm new to geospatial data and need a way to get data out of a CSV in this format:

`Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Timestamp, Trip Identifier`

and into a geojson suitable for `kepler.gl` with their specified format:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "vendor": "A",
      "vol":20},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-74.20986, 40.81773, 0, 1564184363],
          [-74.20987, 40.81765, 0, 1564184396],
          [-74.20998, 40.81746, 0, 1564184409]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My attempts in Python (heavily based on [code from ewcz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586647/python-script-to-convert-csv-to-geojson)) have not been successful; this returns a ValueError, and I can't see a way to incorporate MultiLineString as the number of coordinate pairs changes between records.

```
import csv, json
from geojson import Feature, FeatureCollection, Point, LineString

features = []
with open('Trips.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='    ')
    for Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Timestamp, ID in reader:
        Latitude, Longitude = map(float, (Latitude, Longitude))
        features.append(
            Feature(
                geometry = LineString([Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Timestamp]),
                properties = {
                    'ID': ID,
                }
            )
        )

collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open("Trips.json", "w") as f:
    f.write('%s' % collection)
```

Error given:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5dadf758869b> in <module>
      9         features.append(
     10             Feature(
---> 11                 geometry = LineString([Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Timestamp]),
     12                 properties = {
     13                     'ID': ID

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geojson/geometry.py in __init__(self, coordinates, validate, precision, **extra)
     30         super(Geometry, self).__init__(**extra)
     31         self["coordinates"] = self.clean_coordinates(
---> 32             coordinates or [], precision)
     33 
     34         if validate:

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geojson/geometry.py in clean_coordinates(cls, coords, precision)
     53                 new_coords.append(round(coord, precision))
     54             else:
---> 55                 raise ValueError("%r is not a JSON compliant number" % coord)
     56         return new_coords
     57 

ValueError: '0' is not a JSON compliant number
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace and point to the line that throw the error? Can you share the csv as well?

Comment: Updated question with errors. An extract of the CSV is [here](https://github.com/jamang1999/hello-world/blob/master/Trips.csv). The last line of the error message rejects any number in the third column of the CSV (Altitude).

Comment: the link to the csv does not work. Upload it to pastebin or try another link.

Comment: See my answer - I think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you are passing strings to API that needs numbers.

```
for Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Timestamp, ID in reader
```

should be replaced with code that will transform the strings into numbers. something like:

```
for float(Latitude), float(Longitude), int(Altitude), int(Timestamp), ID in reader
```

Data example:

```
51.467525   -0.445004   0   1569324754  EIN159
```

So it looks like that the first 2 fields are float numbers , fields 3,4 are ints and field 5 is a string.