# how to create a geojson polygon with lat long coordinates?

Tags: gis, polygon, geojson

I have a CSV file with 2 columns that comprise of lat/long points. I want create a geojson polygon by connecting all these dots. Everything that I am finding is using qgis etc.. is there a simpler way of doing this? I'm not familiar with that tool.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586647/python-script-to-convert-csv-to-geojson

Comment: Not quite. The output geojson is saving as individual points and not connecting as a polygon.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294206/create-a-polygon-from-coordinates-in-geopandas-with-python I think this is what I'm looking for.